# Jenkins Jcloud and digitalocean provisionning

Tags: jenkins, digital-ocean, jclouds

I'm trying to provision digitalocean droplet through jenkins jcloud plugin but am having a hard time knowing what to put.

First of all is this the right endpoint url for the api v2?:
https://api.digitalocean.com/v2

In digitalocean I've created an APP and I was given the Identity and Secret key I provided to jenkins.

But when connecting I get this error

```
Cannot connect to specified cloud, please check the identity and
 credentials: status cannot be null connecting to GET 
https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/droplets HTTP/1.1
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: did you get a way to resolve this?

Comment: no I just switched to docker

Answer (score 1):

You do not need add endpoint.

Only add one credential, with password (token). And that is it. Like this:

[image: Image example]